# function.php files not loading

Tags: php, wordpress

I decided to try building a theme without using a foundation like underscores etc... I have all the required files

([ss of files](http://prntscr.com/b6aeiy)),

my `functions.php` file looks like this:

[functions file](http://prntscr.com/b6af2d),

and I am trying to load this file to enqueue all my css:

[ss of enqueue-scripts file](http://prntscr.com/b6afvv).

This has worked on other themes I did based off underscores so I assume I am missing some function that perhaps controls the pathing?

Added a message to console.log to see the pages were being loaded and on all of them I do get the message back, so I assume they must be pathing. Is there a way to check or set the `get_template_directory_uri`?

Comment: You should add your code as inline text (properly formatted) and not as images.

Comment: Agreed about inline `code`. If you have to use images, you should also use [the *official* imgur service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/292533).

Comment: Do you call [`wp_head()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) in your header file?

Comment: *facepalm* was missing the wp_head, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
require __DIR__ . "/functions.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gerald, was missing the wp_head